# Rails keep existing value and add more values to array

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm trying to keep the exist value of an array `@account.images` and add the values of `new_images` to the array like this:

```
def add_more_images(new_images)
    @account = Account.find(params[:id])
    @images = [@account.images]
    @images += [new_images]
    @account.assign_attributes({ :images => @images })
end
```

This what I have in the strong params `{images: []}`

This is what I get from `@account.images:

`[#<AttachmentUploader:0x007f98699482f8 @model=#<Account id: 1, business_name: "Example Account", business_description: "There are many variations of passages of Lorem Ips...", web_site: "www.example.com", phone_number: "", street: "", zip_code: "6021", country: "", store_id: 1, city: "", state: "", created_at: "2018-03-04 14:39:23", updated_at: "2018-03-13 09:19:30", images: [nil, nil, nil, "image8.jpg"]>, @mounted_as=:images, @storage=#<CarrierWave::Storage::File:0x007f9869948258 @uploader=#<AttachmentUploader:0x007f98699482f8 ...>>, @file=#<CarrierWave::SanitizedFile:0x007f986a1f3ce0 @file="/Users/RubymineProjects/pinsle/public/uploads/account/images/1/image8.jpg", @original_filename=nil, @content_type=nil>, @versions={:thumb=>#<AttachmentUploader::Uploader70146304658160:0x007f986a1f3c90 @model=#<Account id: 1, business_name: "Example Account", business_description: "There are many variations of passages of Lorem Ips...", web_site: "www.example.com", phone_number: "2349875678", street: "", zip_code: "", country: "", store_id: 1, city: "", state: "", created_at: "2018-03-04 14:39:23", updated_at: "2018-03-13 09:19:30", images: [nil, nil, nil, "image8.jpg"]>, @mounted_as=:images, @parent_version=#<AttachmentUploader:0x007f98699482f8 ...>, @storage=#<CarrierWave::Storage::File:0x007f986a1f3bc8 @uploader=#<AttachmentUploader::Uploader70146304658160:0x007f986a1f3c90 ...>>, @file=#<CarrierWave::SanitizedFile:0x007f986a1f36a0 @file="/Users/RubymineProjects/pinsle/public/uploads/account/images/1/thumb_image8.jpg", @original_filename=nil, @content_type=nil>, @versions={}>, :mini=>#<AttachmentUploader::Uploader70146304645520:0x007f986a1f3c68 @model=#<Account id: 1, business_name: "Example Account", business_description: "There are many variations of passages of Lorem Ips...", web_site: "www.example.com", phone_number: "2349875678", street: "", zip_code: "", country: "", store_id: 1, city: "", state: "", created_at: "2018-03-04 14:39:23", updated_at: "2018-03-13 09:19:30", images: [nil, nil, nil, "image8.jpg"]>, @mounted_as=:images, @parent_version=#<AttachmentUploader:0x007f98699482f8 ...>, @storage=#<CarrierWave::Storage::File:0x007f986a1f35d8 @uploader=#<AttachmentUploader::Uploader70146304645520:0x007f986a1f3c68 ...>>, @file=#<CarrierWave::SanitizedFile:0x007f986a1f30b0 @file="/Users/RubymineProjects/pinsle/public/uploads/account/images/1/mini_image8.jpg", @original_filename=nil, @content_type=nil>, @versions={}>}>]`

This is what I get from `new_images` :

`[#<ActionDispatch::Http::UploadedFile:0x007f986a2096a8 @tempfile=#<Tempfile:/var/folders/hq/pr4rt14n7s31v3f6292wtjm00000gn/T/RackMultipart20180313-2377-yox8g6.jpg>, @original_filename="image1.jpg", @content_type="image/jpeg", @headers="Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"account[images][]\"; filename=\"image1.jpg\"\r\nContent-Type: image/jpeg\r\n">]`

And this is the error I get `no implicit conversion of nil into String` on this line : `@account.assign_attributes({ :images => @images })`

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong here and how to make this work?

Comment: Why are you wrapping `@account.images` in another array?

Comment: Hmmm good point @Stefan I deleted the array brackets and I'm still getting the error `no implicit conversion of nil into String`

Comment: How is defined your Account model and the view you upload the image?

Comment: The fact that you have some images equal to nil is not link to the function you showed us. It is present beforehand in @account.images as stated in your logs (the question is now why is it thee and do you actualy want to have `Nil` images?). BTW `new_images` is overwrapped too, you could just write `@images = @account.images + new_images` (not sure if @images should be an attribute here, but that depends on the rest of your code)

Comment: Thanks for the reply @Cyril Lemaire... that is exactly the problem which I can't seem to fix. The nil value! The new images are getting added but the old ones become nil. Also, I tried this `@images = @account.images + new_images` but it returns the same behavior, it updates the new images and deletes the old images. Any ideas why this is happening?

Answer (score 0):

You have to use something like this:

```
def add_more_images(new_images)
    @account = Account.find(params[:id])
    images = @account.images.present? ? @account.images : []
    images << new_images
    @account.update_attributes(images: images)
end
```

Comment: @thanks for the reply @Anija Sara Thomas... the syntax of this  `@account.images : []` is showing wrong

Comment: @Sebastian Palma .... I still get the error `no implicit conversion of nil into String` at this line: `@account.update_attributes(images: images)`